# CSP allowing Base64 encoded images without unsafe-eval

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy, image

If I allow base64 encoded images to load on my website, but I ***do not have*** unsafe-eval enabled, nor have I allowed 'inline-script' would my site still be at risk by allowing base64 encoded image data to be painted onto images that might have malicious script inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A base64 encoded image inside a `<img src="data:...">` will not execute any script, no matter if `unsafe-eval` is enabled or not. It will only display the image. It does not matter if the image contains any script since the browser will  treat it only like a dumb image inside the context of the img tag.

Comment: Is this legit https://www.secjuice.com/hiding-javascript-in-png-csp-bypass/

Comment: this might be a better post of how script injection is happening through a data uri (base65 encoded image) https://www.nccgroup.com/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2019/april/a-novel-csp-bypass-using-data-uri/

Comment: @user1709076: None of these examples execute script inside the image-context. The first one explicitly uses script __outside__ the image in order to load the image and interpret it as Javascript. The problem here is not the base64 image but the malicious script outside which interprets parts of the image as script. The image by itself is harmless. And the malicious script would not actually need the image - all the maliciousness could have been already in the script itself. Its just to obfuscate and keep it smaller.

Comment: This? https://www.paladion.net/blogs/bypass-xss-filters-using-data-uris

Comment: @user1709076: No attacks are shown in this article with img-tag, only within object. Again img enforces image context and the data are thus interpreted as image and not script.